# Quantitative Freivalds' algorithm

Tags: probability, reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

I recently became aware of [Freivalds' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freivalds%27_algorithm): Given $n\times n$ matrices $A, B, C$, we can test whether $A\cdot B = C$ by simply multiplying either side with $k$  random vectors and check whether the results coincide. Since the failure rate of the test  decreases exponentially as $\mathcal O(2^{-k})$, in practice we only need to test $k\ll n$ vectors.

Now there are 2 issues with this:

1. Due to round-off errors, even if $AB=C$ we shouldn't expect $ABv=Cv$ *exactly* when computing with floating point numbers
2. If the test fails, we only know $AB\neq C$, but not *how* unequal they *likely* are, e.g. measured in terms of a matrix norm

So is there a *quantitative* version of Freivalds' algorithm, that can tell me something about $\|AB-C\|$, given $\|ABv_i - Cv_i\|$ for random vectors $(v_i)_{i=1\ldots k}$?
E.g. an error bound of the following form would be nice:

> If $\|ABv_i - Cv_i\|\le \epsilon$ for random vectors $(v_i)_{i=1\ldots k}$ then $\|AB-C\|\le \mathcal O(g(\epsilon))$ with probability at least $p_k$

PS: Should there be a tag for probabilistic algorithms / probabilistic numerics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HMT error bound (see [Lemma 4.1](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/090771806?casa_token=v5sezFWOPU0AAAAA:LGtGHJAzpPJuSKx9-qvdng7_Mp7NiU1dpFEpg0Kwf0ocZ1DpToB4uYsaBOIxgKhHQ9N1lRLTjw)) accomplishes this goal. For $E = AB - C$,

$$
\|E\|\le \alpha \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \max_{i=1,2,\ldots,k} \|E v_i\| \mbox{ with probability } \ge 1-\alpha^k
$$

where $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are independent vectors with IID standard normal entries and $\|\cdot\|$ the spectral (operator $2$-) norm. This is precisely the resume you as for with $g(\epsilon) = \alpha \sqrt{2/\pi}$ and $p_k = 1-\alpha^k$.